# Newly created records in domain not shown in field OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I have been working on a search module in OpenERP-7.  I am returning records in domain so that I can show them on my field. The problem is that the field is not showing the newly created records in the domain. While on printing the value of domain on console, I get the desired records. But I don't seem to get why it's not allowing me to view them in my field. Neither I am getting any error.

My domain part of function is as follows:

```
 res = cr.fetchall()
    for p_id,p_name in res:
        domain.append((p_id))
    print domain
    return {'domain':{'my_products':[('id','in',domain)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see records in a one2many, you don't have to use 'domain', you must use 'value' with the template to save one2many records (see in server/bin/openerp/osv/fields.py around the line 420) :

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------                     
# Relationals fields                                                            
# ---------------------------------------------------------                     
#                                                                                
#                                                                               
# Values: (0, 0,  { fields })    create                                         
#         (1, ID, { fields })    update                                         
#         (2, ID)                remove (delete)                                
#         (3, ID)                unlink one (target id or target of relation)   
#         (4, ID)                link                                           
#         (5)                    unlink all (only valid for one2many)           
#                                                                               
#CHECKME: dans la pratique c'est quoi la syntaxe utilisee pour le 5? (5) ou (5, 0)?
```

So, in your case, I think this could work :

```
res = cr.fetchall()
for p_id,p_name in res:
    domain.append((p_id))

return {'value': {'my_products': [(4, x) for x in domain]}}
```